# Set WCF Service Configuration in code Behind in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-config

I want to Use WCF Service in Asp.net I had Add Refrence in Web site.i don't want to Update my Web.Config File.

I want to Handle WCF Service from Code Behind.All Configuration property like

```
 WSHttpBinding
 EndpointIdentity
 Uri
 ContractDescription
```

handle form code behind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an end point using the address and also based on the binding supported by the web service, you can create the Binding and then you will just create the proxy and consume the service.

```
// Specify an end point address of the service
EndpointAddress endpointAdress = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);

// Create the binding to be used by the service
BasicHttpBinding binding1 = new BasicHttpBinding();

//customize the binding configurations like the ones below
 binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 );
    binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 );
    binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 );
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 10 );

//create the client proxy using the specific endpoint and binding you have created
YourServiceClient proxy = new YourServiceClient(binding1, endpointAddress);
```

Or you can use the `ChannelFactory` to follow a generic approach which is shown in the How-To guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx)

Comment: Where did `YourServiceClient` come from?